# Is there anyway to get efficientnet pre-trained weight in hdf5 format?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, efficientnet

I have some problems with getting pre-trained weights in efficientnet. So I googled for efficientnet.hdf5 but cannot find it. So is there anyway to get pre-trained weight in hdf5 format. Thank u.

Answer (score 2):

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import EfficientNetB0, EfficientNetB5

model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=True, weights="imagenet", input_tensor=None, input_shape=None, pooling=None, classes=1000, classifier_activation="softmax")
model.summary()

# Keras H5 format(older method)
model.save("my_model.h5")

# TensorFlow SavedModel format(recommended)
model.save("my_model")
```

Comment: Could you also add some text to explain your answer (in general avoid just posting code as answers)